# Select a checkbox with square brackets in id and name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot select a checkbox `id="Slot[2014-01-01][1][1]"` with JQuery.

I've tried:

```
$('#Slot[2014-01-01][1][1]')
$('#Slot\\[2014-01-01\\]\\[1\\]\\[1\\]')
$('#Slot\\[2014\\-01\\-01\\]\\[1\\]\\[1\\]')
$('#Slot\\\\[2014-01-01\\\\]\\\\[1\\\\]\\\\[1\\\\]')
$('#Slot\\\\[2014\\\\-01\\\\-01\\\\]\\\\[1\\\\]\\\\[1\\\\]')
```

...and all the combinations with `Slot` to lowercase `slot`.

What's driving me crazy is the fact that the Label `for="Slot[2014-01-01][1][1]"` works fine, even if I place it on a far away (HTML-wise) modal and call it with a later AJAX query.

I need this to apply CSS styling, and using `$checkbox.is(':checked')` is much more reliable than `$label.on('click')`.

Thanks

Comment: How about `$('#Slot\[2014-01-01\]\[1\]\[1\]')`?

Comment: `$('#Slot\\[2014-01-01\\]\\[1\\]\\[1\\]')` worked for me

Comment: You can use https://mothereff.in/css-escapes to figure out how to escape css selectors. According to that tool - `$('#Slot\\[2014-01-01\\]\\[1\\]\\[1\\]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select it via the raw id attribute.

```
$(':checkbox[id="Slot[2014-01-01][1][1]"]')
```

And if all else fails, this will also work (and is also much quicker) on any element:

```
$(document.getElementById('Slot[2014-01-01][1][1]'))
```